# Android consume huge disk space into system folder

Tags: android, memory, logging, gps, system

I'm running an APP that requires android 4.1 and it's running fine on most of the device, but I've a big problem with a device, the Galaxy Core Prime with 8 GB disk.

It's running Android 5.1.1 and after some day of usage the system gives an error about running out of disk space.

A customer sent me the phone so i could debug it and i saw that the used disk space keeps increasing while running the app, and even removing my app doesn't clean it, so i noticed that the files were allocated into the system folder and i needed to root the phone in order to see what's the problem and so i did.

What i found is that in the data/system/gps/mrvlgps  folder there is a HUGE file called pedatain.dat that takes GB of space and I don't know what is it for and, more important, how to remove it (without root permission)

here a screen with the result of ls -l  [image]

how you see, there is a huge file named pedatain.dat and i don't know what it is, how to remove it (without root permissions) or how to prevent it to be generad or be too big, who knows what i can do?

Comment: are these get created in your app private area that is /data/data/<your package name > .... Please do ls here by rooting a device.

Comment: no it's already in the root space, look at the screenshot: /data/system/gps/mrvlgps

as i said I already rooted the phone, the data is not related to my app, this is the sad part of the question :/

and uninstalling the app or clearing the cache doesn't change anything. it seems just that the phone store some GPS data in that folder but i don't know why and how to prevent that